# C++ filtration using lazy iterator 2

Tags: c++

I have written this code to print out 17.5, 25.0

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Callable>
struct FilteringIterator : Iterator {
    using OriginalIterator = Iterator; // required for accessing the used Iterator type from other locations

    Iterator m_end;
    Callable callable;

    FilteringIterator(Iterator m_begin, Iterator m_end, Callable callable) : Iterator{m_begin}, m_end{m_end}, callable{callable} { }
    Iterator& get_orig_iter() { return ((Iterator&)*this); }
    double operator*() {
        while (true) {
            if (get_orig_iter() != m_end) {
                if(callable(*get_orig_iter()) == 1) {
                    return *get_orig_iter();
                } else {
                    get_orig_iter()++;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(callable(*get_orig_iter()) == 1) {
            return *get_orig_iter();
        } 
        return *get_orig_iter();
    }
};

auto filter = [](auto action) {
    return [=](auto& container) {
        using Container = std::decay_t<decltype(container)>;
        using Iterator = typename Container::iterator;
        using IteratorX = FilteringIterator<Iterator, decltype(action)>;
        return Range{IteratorX{container.begin(), container.end(), action}, IteratorX{container.end(), container.end(), action}};
    };
};
```

I need a lazy iterator that will traverse over a range and filter it lazily. For example,

```
auto v = std::vector<double>{};
auto odd_gen = views::odds();

for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    v.push_back(odd_gen() * 2.5);
// v contains {2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5} here

new_line();
for(auto a : v | filter(greater_than(15))) // filter is applied lazily as the range is traversed
    std::cout << a  << std::endl;
```

// print { 17.5, 22.5} here

```
     new_line();
for(auto a : v | filter(less_than(15))) // filter is applied lazily as the range is traversed
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

//  prints 2.5, 7.5 and 12.5

but now, I want it to print out `2.5, 7.5, 12.5` but i couldn't manage to do that. What can I do?

Comment: please provide a compilable [mre], the expected output, actual output or compiler error messages

Comment: Please **DON'T** tag with every single existing version of C++ (and most importantly **not** with C). Either your problem is related to a specific version (in that case tag *only that version*) or it's related to C++ in general (in that case don't tag with any specific version). I'm removing those tags since the latter seems to be the case.

Comment: Is it normal that your filtering is done on `operator*` instead of `operator++` (and it seems you then deference end iterator).

Comment: We're missing the definitions of `greater_than` and `less_than` and `Range`